# error: Non-nullable instance field 'screenSize' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, game-engine, flame

I am pretty new to flame and flutter but I was just trying to set up the basis for a game project I am working on and it is telling me that the field "screenSize", as well as "tileSize", must be initialized.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class GameController extends Game {
  Size screenSize;
  double tileSize;

  GameController() {
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect background = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    Paint backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = Color(0xFFFAFAFA);
    canvas.drawRect(background, backgroundPaint);
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {}

  void resize(Size size) {
    screenSize = size;
    tileSize = screenSize.width / 10;
  }

  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Flame, extend `BaseGame` and not `Game`.
`BaseGame` will give you everything you need from the game engine meanwhile with `Game` you have to implement everything yourself.

You can check a basic example [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/packages/flame/example/lib/main.dart), and there are some more examples on https://examples.flame-engine.org/

There are some good tutorials on YouTube too.

Flawn's answer is correct about the values having to be initialized too, but in `BaseGame` you would automatically have the `size` of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't worked with Flame but that's just the Dart-specific view on what you COULD do)

You have two options:

1. Set the types of `screenSize` and `tileSize` nullable, the types would be then `Size?` and `double`
2. Set initial values for both variables (either hard-code or over the constructor)

I don't know what you want to do, but it might be a good practice to set them initially over the second option.